# Having trouble with char pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm having trouble with char pointers. I'm trying to get the value from the `store_stuff` function and print it into the main function. How can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void store_stuff(char *name, int *age);
int main(void) {

    char *name;
    int age;

    store_stuff(&name, &age); // I'm having trouble here

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

}

void store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {

    *name = "John";
    *age = 31;

}
```

Comment: If you intend to pass `&name` then `store_stuff()` should have `char **name` and assign `*name`. Better would be `const char*`/`const char**`. (Otherwise I'm afraid the compiler complaints as `"John"` is `const` as well.) Btw. this does not compile: `age` vs. `value`.

Comment: You should use double pointer.

Comment: @Scheff I updated my first first, still not compiling...

Comment: If you permanently change your question, it is hard to answer...

Comment: @Scheff Sorry, I won't change my code. I tried what you said, but it didn't work

Comment: Here we go: [**Live demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/riXAbLmPZPhUZYXQ)

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a problem description. If it doesn't compile, what's the error message?

Comment: Thank you @Scheff!!

Comment: change function declaration

Comment: Please, be aware: If you intend to assign constant string literals only this works fine. If you build up strings (`strcat()`, `strcpy()`) you need to allocate memory for this. Now, you have a new problem: `free()`ing of constant string literals is not allowed but you should it if you `malloc()`ed before.

Comment: in function declaration must be **name

Comment: @Scheff Is there a better way to store a char and use it like I did in my code and not use malloc?

Comment: There is only one way: A pointer does not allocate anything. It just points to somewhere (or nowhere if it is `NULL`). Somewhere has to have its storage. This may be a global variable, a local variable, or something allocated with `malloc()`. Don't forget - a local array provides storage until you leave the enclosing scope (`{ }`). Though, a local array in `main()` has a sufficient life-time as any function called in `main()` returns before `main()` returns.

Comment: ...and a constant string literal has a storage as well. (It's allocated by the compiler.) Of course, you may not change a constant string literal. Even if you do it like that: `const char *pc = "a constant string"; char *c = (char*)pc; /* Oh, oh */ strcpy(c, "even shorter");` Most compilers/platforms secure the constant things and you will end up in a crash.

Comment: @Scheff if I add `free(name);` at the end of the `store_stuff` function, it will be okay?

Comment: You may `free(name);` if you `name = malloc(/* some size*/);` before. If you try this: `name = "John"; free(name);` you probably end up in a crash. You may not `free()` what's not allocated with `malloc()` (or `calloc()`). You may not double `free()` (the same pointer). Any violation corrupts your heap management and will lead to any kind of brain ache. A corrupted heap may cause a crash soon or later. If it crashs soon you're lucky. If it crashs later you will have a hard time to find the error. (SO is ful with questions regarding this.) ;-)

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Nope, what you're storing in _name_ is the address of the first byte of the string literal "John". String literals are stored in Read-Only memory

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov and as Scheff pointed out, malloc functions, (malloc, calloc, realloc.) set some data somewhere, normally and the end of the allocated block, which this functions, including free(), needs to get their job done, without this, how does free knows how much memory to free?.

Comment: It still not works?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: When I wrote "allocate" I meant providing storage in any way. (E.g. `void func() { char local[10]; /* allocates array of 10 char on stack */ }`.) Heap storage you get with `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` (TY @Jenny). Only such heap storage might/should be `free()`-ed. Stack storage is free-d automatically when you leave the scope. Global storage is free-d automatically when you exit the owning process. (...and `free()` _may not_ be used for this.)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/5HOPGQ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *store_stuff(char **name, int *age);
int main(void) {

    char *name;
    int age;

    store_stuff(&name, &age); // I'm having trouble here

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

}

char *store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {

    *name = "John";
    *age = 31;
    return *name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make it

```
void store_stuff(char** name, int* age)
{
    *name = "John";
    *age = 31;
}
```

You need that pointer to a pointer for name assignment to make its way out of store_stuff

Also you need to change your definition of

`char name`

to

`char* name`

Since `name` itself wants to be a pointer to interact as a string

EDIT: And of course, be sure to make your prototype consistent at the top with `void store_stuff(char** name, int* age);`

Comment: @Malachi I updated my first post, to your code, but it didn't work

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov never change functionality of code in your question, this makes answers look silly!

Comment: Yeah for future reference, leave your original code as is.  Tell us what the error is.  Probably const-related ...